# Modify file on server from client side c#

Tags: c#, pdf, client-side, server-side

I want to open a pdf, edit it and save it on the server.

It uses to work on my local machine :

I save an editable pdf on the server and then open it with :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@pathFile);
```

Now that i deployed the web application on a IIS server, i understand that Process.Start won't work anymore or will open the pdf on the server side but i don't know how to make it possible from the client side.

I know I can download the pdf, edit it and upload it again (It's how it works at this moment), but i wanted something easier and faster for the users.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just flush the content to the browser. If they have abode reader installed or they are using a browser with PDF viewing capability, it will work. Otherwise they will receive the download this file message.

```
var pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\path\DynamicCrosstabSampleRpt.pdf"); // or an in-memory byte array
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdf.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
// try inline mode as well
// Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=test.pdf");
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.OutputStream.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
Response.OutputStream.Flush();
Response.OutputStream.Close();
Response.End();
```

Comment: This will only allow me to read the pdf isn't it ? If i want to save the new pdf to the server i have to upload it again right ?